# HDMI audio to Samsung TV not working Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, sound, pulseaudio, hdmi

I have seen many people have had problems with this topic and have tried pretty much every solution I can find (google is an ubuntu users friend) but still have not been able to get audio working through HDMI on my laptop with Ubuntu 14.04 (I also had the same problem with 13.10 and 13.04). Hence why I am writing this ask ubuntu question (my last hope). When I was running Windows 7 this was not an issue.

```
Laptop Information: 
3.13.0-24-generic
Graphics: Hybrid Graphics System
GPU/VPU: Intel HD Graphics 3000 and NVIDIA GeForce GT 555M
```

I am currently running the `NVIDIA binary driver - version 331.38` (from additional drivers)
I also tried using the X.org Xserver - Nouveau display driver
Additionally I installed the oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms (alsa daily builds)

Information:
The option for HDMI audio does not show up under sound settings so I installed the pulseaudio manager. However the option for HDMI output is always showing up as (unplugged). I also tried the gnome alsamixer with no luck.

With the alsamixer I can see the option for S/PDIF and even when I unmute it no option appears in the sound settings.

I added the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="radeon.audio=1"` option to the `/etc/default/grub` just for fun...

I checked all the settings on the TV just to make sure I wasn't missing anything.

I even tried the Bumblebee Project.

Let me know if I need to provide any additional information.

Comment: Nvidia GTX 560Ti, Samsung TV, same situation. After installing and removing VLC phonon backend can't even test HDMI output in KDE settings. 3.13.0-24

Comment: audio works with nouveau drivers, but they don't see FullHD resolution, just 1280x800

Comment: It started working again today, check yours please.

Comment: The audio is not working with the nouveau drivers or the nvidia drivers... 
I also tried the pavucontrol and the 
"Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output" and 
"Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output" still show up as (unplugged).

Answer (score 2):

Somehow KDE phonon settings don't show the needed HDMI output.
The latest `pavucontrol` will show much more outputs with addition of `plugged in`/`unplugged` prefixes. Just select `plugged in` one.

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me. My issue (14.04) was with Nvidia through HDMI. I don't know what exactly I did; I just tinkered with the settings until sound came on.